# Does Samsung Galaxy Note 10 support USB C-to-HDMI?

Tags: samsung, hdmi, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1, usb-c

Can Samsung Galaxy Note 10 do video over USB C to HDMI?

I called one of the companies that makes a USB C hub with HDMI and they said no. They said my phone does not support DisplayPort Alt Mode, but [the Samsung website](https://www.samsung.com/uk/support/mobile-devices/i-smashed-my-screen-and-cannot-use-the-touchscreen-is-there-any-way-to-access-my-data/) shows an adapter like that.

How can I display my Note 10 on a monitor or TV? My Note 10 screen is broken, so I can't make any changes on the phone.

Comment: If the Samsung website shows such an adapter why don't you include the link in your question? Furthermore is the adapter shown in combination with a Note 10? Because some Samsung phones may have support for such adapter but may be not yours (e.g.. those with full Dex support).

Comment: @Robert added the link to their article. Note 9 and 10 has dex without special cable. But I not talking about dex. Talking about connecting directly to monitor not a pc.

Comment: I talked to Samsung reps and they give me a wide array of answers. From yes to no to yours was an earlier model and only new 10s support it then back to yes  and no. Even got it depends on your monitor. So was hoping someone here has a real answer

Comment: Seems you need an answer from someone who owns a Note 10 to get a definitive answer. As this is a place not specific to Samsung or Note10 the chance is a bit low to find someone who knows the answer. In my opinion your chance would be higher when posting in a forum that is Note 10 specific but there you should name you exact model name e.g. SM-N970F as gsmarena lists 8 variants for Galaxy Note 10.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 10+ and my screen is also broken.

I've been using my phone through Samsung DeX for the past 3 years with the screen broken.

So the answer is yes. You can get a Type C to HDMI cable or a Type C HUB and connect your phone to an external monitor and use your phone while the phone screen is broken.